# Angular FormControl Error in console from displaying template based on function call

Tags: angular, angular-forms

As of now I have a form that will display each column dynamically based on its type ('text',boolean, etc) through a function call into the ng-template-outlet. It works too!

The only problem is that I get this errors that I've posted below in the console, and don't understand why. I've posted my code below.

[image: Console log error 1]
[image: Console log error 2]
HTML

```
<form *ngIf="filteredColumns && filteredColumns.length" [formGroup]="metaForm" class="row" [ngClass]="{ 'device-sso': isSsoQrDevice$ | async }">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!displayAsRow">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of filteredColumns">
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="getColumnInputType(column) | async"
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="getColumnInputType(column) | async"
          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: column }"
        ></ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="displayAsRow">
      <c-form-row *ngFor="let column of filteredColumns" [title]="column.title" [description]="column.description" class="w-100">
        <ng-container
          *ngIf="getColumnInputType(column) | async"
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="getColumnInputType(column) | async"
          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: column }"
        ></ng-container>
      </c-form-row>
    </ng-container>
  </form>

<ng-template #text typeTemplate="text" let-column>
  <div *cHasRole="checkPermissions(column.permissions)" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content col-3 mb-3">
    <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{ 'col-11': column?.description }" appearance="outline" stateChange="onFieldChange(column)">
      <mat-label>{{ column.title | translate }} {{ column.validation && column.validation.required ? ' *' : '' }}</mat-label>
      <input matInput [formControlName]="column.field" [readonly]="checkColumnReadOnly(column)" />
      <mat-hint *ngIf="column.hintLabel">{{ column.hintLabel }}</mat-hint>
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkValidationErrors(column, 'required')">
        {{ util.formatFormErrorMsg(column.title, 'required') }}
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkValidationErrors(column, 'pattern')">
        {{ util.formatFormErrorMsg(column.title, 'pattern') }}
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <h5 *ngIf="column?.description" class="cursor-pointer col-1 pl-0" [ngbTooltip]="column.description" placement="right-center">
      <i class="far fa-info-circle text-info"></i>
    </h5>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #boolean typeTemplate="boolean" let-column>
  <mat-form-field *cHasRole="checkPermissions(column.permissions)" floatLabel="always" appearance="none" class="col-3 mb-3" stateChange="onFieldChange(column)">
    <mat-slide-toggle [formControlName]="column.field">
      <span> {{ column.title | translate }}{{ column.validation && column.validation.required ? ' *' : '' }}</span>
    </mat-slide-toggle>
    <textarea class="hidden" matInput hidden></textarea>
    <mat-error *ngIf="checkValidationErrors(column, 'required')">
      {{ util.formatFormErrorMsg(column.title, 'required') }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

Directive

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[typeTemplate]'
})
export class TypeTemplateDirective {
  @Input() typeTemplate: string;
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

TS

```
 @ViewChildren(TypeTemplateDirective) typeTemplateDirectives: QueryList<TypeTemplateDirective>;



getColumnInputType(column: any): any {
    let columnType: string;
    if (column.type.toLowerCase() === 'datetime' || column.type.toLowerCase() === 'date' || column.type.toLowerCase() == 'boolean') {
      columnType = column.type.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      columnType = column.inputMetaData.inputType.toLowerCase();
    }

    return of(this.typeTemplateDirectives).pipe(
      filter(directives => !!directives.length),
      map(directives => directives?.find(ttd => ttd.typeTemplate === columnType).templateRef)
    );
  }
```